# What commands are counted as 'cheats'?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

When making a new world, on the screen where you can turn on the Bonus Chest, Structures etc. you have a button for turning on Cheats.

Now I know the command `/gamemode <mode> [player]` can not be used, looking up on the [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Command) it says

> The majority of commands are only available in the following situations:

- In a Minecraft multiplayer server game, entered by an operator or command block.
- In other multiplayer games, entered by the player who opened a LAN game with cheats enabled, or is hosting their own multiplayer server
- **In singleplayer, if cheats were enabled at world creation (via the "More World Options..." button). 


  Some player commands are also available in singleplayer even when cheats are not enabled.**

However I can't see which commands are considered cheats or not.

So I am wondering what other commands can't be used if Cheats is set to no, or if it is easier to list what commands can be used (as there are a lot of commands).

I am referring to Vanilla Minecraft

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are several commands that can be used in survival without cheats enabled. These generally are commands that do not have any effect on gameplay, hence you are not cheating.

Here is a list of the commands that can be operated without cheats:

`/help` - Displays help about other commands

`/me` - Writes a message relating to the player

`/tell` - Private message

`/seed` - Displays the world seed

`/trigger` - Can change enabled "trigger" type objectives

These commands do not require cheats, because they do not give the player any advantage. I think I have covered all the commands that are applicable to singleplayer, however I may have missed some. Let me know if I have.

Comment: Also servers will have plugins that add commands which do not require you to be OP to use.

Comment: /save is a OP level command.

Answer (score 5):

I think you are looking for the "OP" commands, as listed on the [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Minecraft_Wiki), under [Commands](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#Summary_of_commands). You are pretty much looking for any command listed as 'OP Only':

> **/achievement**Gives or removes an achievement from a player.
> **/ban**Adds player to banlist.
> **/ban-ip**   Adds IP address to banlist.
> **/banlist**  Displays banlist.
> **/blockdata**    Modifies the data tag of a block.
> **/clear**    Clears items from player inventory.
> **/clone**    Copies blocks from one place to another.
> **/debug**    Starts or stops a debugging session.
> **/defaultgamemode**  Sets the default game mode.
> **/deop**     Revoke operator status from a player.
> **/difficulty**   Sets the difficulty level.
> **/effect**   Add or remove status effects.
> **/enchant**  Enchants a player item.
> **/entitydata** Modifies the data tag of an entity.
> **/execute**  Executes another command.
> **/fill**     Fills a region with a specific block.
> **/gamemode**     Sets a player's game mode.
> **/gamerule**     Sets or queries a game rule value.
> **/give**     Gives an item to a player.
> **/kick**     Kicks a player off a server.
> **/kill**     Kills entities (players, mobs, items, etc.).
> **/list**     Lists players on the server.
> **/op**   Grants operator status to a player.
> **/pardon**   Removes entries from the banlist.
> **/particle**     Creates particles.
> **/playsound**    Plays a sound.
> **/publish**  Opens single-player world to local network.
> **/replaceitem**  Replaces items in inventories.
> **/save-all**     Saves the server to disk.
> **/save-off**     Disables automatic server saves.
> **/save-on**  Enables automatic server saves.
> **/say**  Displays a message to multiple players.
> **/scoreboard**   Manages objectives, players, and teams.
> **/seed**     Displays the world seed.
> **/setblock**     Changes a block to another block.
> **/setidletimeout**   Sets the time before idle players are kicked.
> **/setworldspawn**    Sets the world spawn.
> **/spawnpoint**   Sets the spawn point for a player.
> **/spreadplayers**    Teleports entities to random locations.
> **/stats**    Update objectives from command results.
> **/stop**     Stops a server.
> **/summon**   Summons an entity.
> **/tellraw**  Displays a JSON message to players.
> **/testfor**  Counts entities matching specified conditions.
> **/testforblock**     Tests whether a block is in a location.
> **/testforblocks**    Tests whether the blocks in two regions match.
> **/time**     Changes or queries the world's game time.
> **/title**    Manages screen titles.
> **/toggledownfall**   Toggles the weather.
> **/tp**   Teleports entities.
> **/weather**  Sets the weather.
> **/whitelist**    Manages server whitelist.
> **/worldborder**  Manages the world border.
> **/xp**   Adds or removes player experience.

Comment: While we accept answers, link-only answers are not welcome. Do you think you could summarize what's on that page? (PS: You'll have to use ASCII tables should you choose to use one)